# FileNotFoundError: when creating new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Want to backup files to different directory.

As the files are backed up quite nicely, but when program encounters a folders it fetches a error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:/Users/kemburaj.kemburaj-PC/Desktop/backup.py", line 16, in   <module>
     fhand = open(file,'wb') 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\kemburaj.kemburaj-PC\\Documents\\backup\\a\\Appointment Reciept.pdf'
```

My code is:

```
import os

for dirname, dirs, filename in os.walk("."):
    for file in filename:
        thefile = os.path.join(dirname,file)
        source = open(thefile,'rb')
        data = source.read()
        source.close()
        Newpath = "C:\\Users\kemburaj.kemburaj-PC\Documents\\backup\\" #paste the backup directory path, please check escape characters
        if not os.path.exists(Newpath):
            os.makedirs(Newpath)
        file = os.path.join(Newpath,thefile[2:]) #copy this py file in the directory which is to be backed up
        print(file)
        fhand = open(file,'wb')
        fhand.write(data)
        fhand.close()
        print("\n\nBackup >",file)
```

Comment: `file` is a reserved built-in symbol name, try using another name for your variables.

Comment: Tried, fhand = open(newfile,'wb')   But still shows error.

Comment: `C:\Users\kemburaj.kemburaj-PC\Documents\backup\a` is different to `C:\Users\kemburaj.kemburaj-PC\Documents\backup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shutil.copytree()` instead.
Something like:

```
shutil.copytree('.', Newpath)
```

would do.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this:

```
file = os.path.join(Newpath,thefile[2:])
```

Returns a path that includes a subdirectory name `a` that you haven't yet created.

This is the path that is returned as problematic in your stacktrace:

```
C:\Users\kemburaj.kemburaj-PC\Documents\backup\a\Appointment Reciept.pdf
```

Comment: yes, but directory creation is also done using ,     if not os.path.exists(Newpath):
            os.makedirs(Newpath)